# how to retrieve data from fire-store document collection data with out mentioning specific collection name?

Tags: firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on angular 5 with firebase firestore.I inserted data into fire-store collection/document/collection/document/collection/document then set data the last document.But at the time retrieving data I am giving only first collection name then I want complete root data.but I am getting only field in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

checkout:List subcollections of a document

As we know querying in Cloud Firestore is shallow by default. This type of query isn't supported, although it is something Google may consider in the future.